# Move 300 images from a folder (contains 800 images) to another based on file name list

Tags: excel, shell, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I need to move 300 images from a folder (contains 800 images) to another folder. The file name list of these 300 images are available in the excel format. Is it possible to move them via programming instead of search the file and move it one by one? Our IT told me he can't separate these files. Do you have any solution? Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: There are many excel formats. Which one is the list in? XLS? XLSX? CSV? XML? Can you save the list as a different format? (I've got an idea, but it requires the list to be in the CSV format.)

Comment: Are the images in sequential order?  Like 300 to 600?  Or something like that..  If so, you can use a FOR /L in a batch script to count.  Or, if you have access to the mapped drive, you can do it in Windows Explorer about 500 times faster than cobbling together some code you are going to use only one time..  It does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing this - I am assuming you are on Windows. First, save text file called `ListOfImages.txt` that contains the names of the images you wish to move - put one image on each line and include the extension. Then, save the following into a file called `movefiles.cmd`:

```
@echo off
set Source=C:\Users\YourName\Desktop\moving\MovingFrom
set Target=C:\Users\YourName\Desktop\moving\MovingTo
set FileList=C:\Users\YourName\Desktop\moving\ListOfImages.txt
echo.

if not exist "%Source%" echo Source folder "%Source%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%FileList%" echo File list "%FileList%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%Target%" md "%Target%"

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('type "%FileList%"') do move "%Source%\%%a" "%Target%"

:Exit
echo.
echo press the Space Bar to close this window.
pause > nul
```

You will want to change the variables for `Source`, `Target`, and `FileList` to match where you have those folders and the `ListOfImages.txt` on your machine. After you have saved this file (make sure it has the `.cmd` extension, you should be able to double-click it and it will run the commands in your `Command Prompt`.

For example, say my **MovingFrom** folder contains the following:

[image: MovingFromFolder]

And I only want to move `Image1.png` and `Image2.png` -- then my `ListOfImages.txt` file would like this:

[image: ListOfImages.txt File]

After running `moveFiles.cmd` (provided I have changed the necessary variables to point to the right folders/places on my machine), my MovingTo folder should contain the following:

[image: MovingToFolder]

Notice that `Image2.png` was not moved because it was not listed in the `ListOfImages.txt` text file.